# Can enderman hold items?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there any probability that an Enderman can pick up an item/blocks that are lying on the ground? I was going to test this myself but I don't think I would be able find the answer unless I look into the code, which I can't do nor understand.

Comment: I think what he's asking here is the probability that an Enderman will pick up a block, not what blocks they can pick up.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Endermen can pick up a [limited number of blocks](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enderman#Moving_blocks).  They can also place these blocks in another location.  They cannot, however, pick up any [entities](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Entities), including all items, such as tools or blocks that have already been broken.

Comment: -1 Question title is misleading, but he does ask for "probability", which your answer doesn't state.

Comment: @Retrosaur: If you read the question again, you'll see that I fully answer the question asked.  The probability is 0.  "Item/blocks that are lying on the ground" are entities: tools, food, broken blocks, etc.

Comment: @Retrosaur: Also, if the question is what your interpretation of it is, even with the source code, it's hard to get a good indication of the probability of an Enderman picking up a block on the whole, as there are so many variables.

Comment: Is the code really that difficult to read?

Comment: @Ric: I honestly don't know, I don't actually have the source code.  The point though, is that it's not a straight `if(rand() > 0.9) pickBlock();` since there's a number of checks that would have to be done before that.

Comment: @Ric Except this question, I have no need to download software to read and edit code , so why would I?

Answer (score -2):

if you try

/entitydata @e[type=enderman] {carried:"minecraft:ender_eye"}

the chat will *say an unknown error occurred while attempting to preform this command*
but if you try

/entitydata @e[type=enderman] {carried:"minecraft:wheat"}

it looks hilarious